# How to hide a card in Reactjs?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm  using cards of [antd](https://ant.design/) in reactJS and I need to hide cards.

This is code in my project:

```
                  <div>
                {Survey[1]
                  .Encuesta
                  .map((q, i) => <Card
                    key={i}
                    title={q.tipo + '/' + q.opcion}
                    extra={< a onClick = {
                    () => {
                      Survey[1].Encuesta.splice(q.id-1,1);
                      console.log(Survey[1].Encuesta);

                    }
                  } > Eliminar </a>}
                    style={{
                    width: 500,
                    marginBottom: 10
                  }}>
                    <p>
                      <b>Pregunta:
                      </b>
                      {q.pregunta}</p>
                    <p>
                      <b>opciones:
                      </b>
                      Sin opciones.</p>

                  </Card>)}

              </div>
```

i'm passing a function in Property `extra`:

```
                        extra={< a onClick = {
                    () => {
                      Survey[1].Encuesta.splice(q.id-1,1);
                      console.log(Survey[1].Encuesta);

                    }
                  }
```

I  want to remove the selected object from my array and  also i want to hide it  , please help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
extra={<a onClick = {
                (id) => {
                  Survey[1].Encuesta.filter(q => q.id != id);
                  console.log(Survey[1].Encuesta);
                }}> Eliminar </a>
```

Comment: this code no work :c the error  is "Uncaught TypeError: true is not a function"

Comment: sorry, I made a syntax error. The filter method should take a function, so I've updated it. It's passed q now. so it assume's id is one level deep in each object. If it's deeper, you'll have to map it as appropriate.